# How to access my (java) web app at localhost/app?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, netbeans, port

I'm trying to make small (java) web app using Netbeans 7.4 and Tomcat 7.
Right now I can view it at localhost:8080/app. At localhost/app is only blank page. Is there a way to remove port from URL so my app could be accessed at localhost/app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http default uses port 80. if you set your app to run on that port, you can use just localhost/app